# Convert very long execution mapping into a proper function

Tags: vimrc

I commonly will have a long list of ids that I will need to convert into a tuple for a SQL query or perhaps to create a array in python/javascript. Here is the command I've written to format a list of ids into a tuple and paste it back into the system clipboard:

```
nnoremap & "*pV']J:s/ /,/g<cr>i(<c-o>$)<esc>V"*y
```

How could this be converted into a function? I tried starting but I couldn't even get past the first thing of "paste from clipboard", for example:

```
func FormatInput ()
    call execute("\"*p") " how to get this to execute properly with the leading `"` ?
endfunc
```

While the above one-line might be sufficient for now, I'd like to add things like "quote strings" if the first item is not a digit and stuff like that.

Comment: `execute()` works in command-mode; `p` is a Normal mode command. See `:h :normal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`:normal!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) for the parts that should be executed in Normal mode.

If they include special key codes such as `<C-o>` or `<Esc>`, then use `:execute` so you can use a double quoted string with `\<...>` sequences for the `:normal!` command.

Putting it all together:

```
function! FormatInput()
    normal! "*pV']J
    s/ /,/g
    execute "normal! i(\<c-o>$)\<esc>V\"*y"
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> & :call FormatInput()<CR>
```

Comment: And for those that prefer ex when possible: `put *` (the visual join is unavoidable unfortunately), `s/^/(/ | s/$/)/ | yank *`

Comment: @Filbranden -- thanks, why did you use `normal!` on the first line and then `execute "normal..."` on the third? Is that because of the `<c-o>`?

Comment: @David542 Yes. Like I mentioned a few lines above, if you need special key codes then you need to use `:execute` to be able to add them using escapes in a string. `:map` and friends expand those key codes themselves, that's why that's not needed there.